# Can I make a DIY Cloud server for windows?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, remote-desktop

I asked this question on SO.
[(My Original Post here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970900/can-i-make-a-diy-cloud-server-for-windows)

But they thought it might belong here:

Question:

My old parents have been hacked/virus-ed for the nth time.

I have an old HP server.

I thought of rebuilding it with VMWare (free version) or Oracle virtualbox and having them use windows in a controlled environment. I would back it up and patch it, etc. Maybe they RDC to my server.

I assume I would need a Windows server license to allow multiple connections. (I could also use it for myself to host Plex media server.)

At a 10,000 foot level, is this possible or just a technology quagmire?

Comment: Short answer: yes, it's possible. But the effort will be huge. Better use BSD/Linux NAS

Comment: The question is what use they make of their computer: Do they save files and emails on the local disk, or all they do is browse to websites and use web-mail?

Comment: @Romeo Ninov  Thanks.  You are referring to https://freenas.org/?

Comment: @harrymc They have basics: spreadsheet of accounts and home projects.  Word docs with some medial info and a letter of poor service, etc, etc.  They most browse web.  However, they are hell-bent on using Outlook locally unless I can convice them to use web-mail

Comment: @Romeo Ninov What about installing virtualbox and running windows.  Then I backup the VM and can restore if they corrupt it?  Can I run it from BSD/Linux NAS ?

Comment: If the vector of infection is via the browser, it can be isolated from the rest of the system. Unless they also open doubtful emailed files.

Comment: @Marinaio, you can do it. But think about install some linux on the parents machines...